Need to Update the data of a ASOF_DATE column in a CSV file using shell script
I am trying to update the existing CSV file using shell  script. There is a column called ASOF_DATE where am trying to replace the value of it with the current date. The shell script I am using is not helping me, it's returning blank values for the ASOF_DATE column; can you figure out what's wrong?
Sample Input Data:
ASOF_DATE,CUSIP,Current Face,Market Value
'04/08/2024',BENRDUZU0,-400000000
'04/08/2024',BENRDUZR7,-300000000
'04/08/2024',BENRE4H37,-225000000
'04/08/2024',BENRDUYW7,-250000000

Below is the shell script I am using:
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Argument is missing"
    exit 1
fi

asOnDate=$1
FILE_PATH=/awsdatalake/data/inbound/file/SRC_TPGCF/
if [ ! -f ${FILE_PATH}CFG_ANALYTICS_*.csv ]
then
    echo "File does not exist"
    exit 2
else
    echo "File found."
    for file in ${FILE_PATH}CFG_ANALYTICS_*.csv 
    do
        echo "$file"
        awk -v date="$asof_date" -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {if (NR==1) {print $0} else {if (NR>1) {$1=date; print}}}' "$file" > temp_file && mv temp_file "$file"
    
        echo "Current date $asof_date added to the ASOF_DATE column in $file_path"
    done
fi


The use of single quotes around the first field is weird. Standard CSV would use double quotes around quoted fields.

Tangentially, write diagnostic messages to standard error with >&2 but also maybe don't echo so much.

if [ ! -f ${FILE_PATH}CFG_ANALYTICS_*.csv ] is not how to tell if a directory contains at least 1 file. Google that.

http://shellcheck.net would warn you about that, the issue you're asking about, and other issues.

please update the question with the expected output; also mention what you're using as 'current date' (eg, for current date I am using 7 May 2024)

what is asonDate? is that a typo and should actually be asof_date?

asof_date is just an uninitialized variable, so you are replacing the field with ... nothing. But it's easy to add the variable:
        :
        awk -v date="$(date +%F)" -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","}
            NR>1 {$1=date } 1' "$file" > temp_file &&
        mv temp_file "$file"
        :

You'll notice that I also refactored your Awk script slightly. There are many other problems with your shell script but I'll defer to https://shellcheck.net/ for diagnostics.
If you meant to use (the otherwise unused variable) asOnDate then you might as well use $1 directly.

Able to achieve it using below shell script,
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} {if (NR>1) $1 = "'"$current_date"'"} 1' $file > temp && mv temp $file

Looks like the OP would want date="'$(date +%F)'" with surrounding single quotes.

Your workaround with '"$current_date"' is quite brittle; passing in a string with -v is much more robust. So on the whole, your original attempt was better, but of course needed the correct variable.

@EdMorton Or perhaps $1 = "\047" date "\047". As remarked elsewhere, single quotes in CSV data is weird, and probably just wrong.

It'd just be a bit more efficient to add the quotes once when date is populated rather than every time it's used on every input line but who knows if the OP even actually wants it...

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.csv content be
ASOF_DATE,CUSIP,Current Face,Market Value
'04/08/2024',BENRDUZU0,-400000000
'04/08/2024',BENRDUZR7,-300000000
'04/08/2024',BENRE4H37,-225000000
'04/08/2024',BENRDUYW7,-250000000

then
awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";currdate=strftime("\047%d/%m/%Y\047")}FNR>1{$1=currdate}{print}' file.csv

causes file.csv content (when executed at 7th day of May of 2024 year) to become
ASOF_DATE,CUSIP,Current Face,Market Value
'07/05/2024',BENRDUZU0,-400000000
'07/05/2024',BENRDUZR7,-300000000
'07/05/2024',BENRE4H37,-225000000
'07/05/2024',BENRDUYW7,-250000000

Explanation: I use -i inplace to instruct GNU AWK to change provided file (or files). Inside BEGIN I inform GNU AWK that field separator and output field separator is comma character and use strftime Time Function to prepare current date in dd/mm/YYYY format (I assume you are using big-endian format, adjust according if you need middle-endian date format) encased in ', as it can not be put directed into GNU AWK command I use escape sequence \047. If file number line (FNR) is above one I set 1st field to prepared date. I print every line. Observe that I use FNR rather than NR so it could be used with multiple lines, so you can e.g. ram file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv rather than file.csv
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
